How resize in YOLO impact to model accuracy?
I use YOLOv8X for object detection in photos, and recently I've been wondering about the impact of image size on detection quality. I usually use datasets from Roboflow and apply a resize to 1280x1280 (which results in significantly better performance than the standard resize to 640x640), but the original photos often have aspect ratios far from square, and resizing changes the proportions of objects in the photos. The annotation in the dataset is recalculated for the new photo size, but can changing proportions degrade detection quality? Can I train the model without resizing the input photos? Is it necessary to resize on Roboflow if I can simply specify the parameter imgsz=1280 during training?
I have trained the model both with and without applying resize on Roboflow, and the quality metrics were similar. Some photos from the dataset appear unnaturally stretched after resizing to 1280x1280, which may degrade the model's ability to recognize objects due to changes in their shapes.

You should watch the video that explains the correct size to use.  The optimal size is the one where the smallest objects you want to find will be resized in such a way that it can easily be found by the network you are using.  You can find that here:  https://youtu.be/m3Trxxt9RzE
There is also an entry for this topic in the YOLO FAQ:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#optimal_network_size
Why limit yourself to 640x640 or 1280x1280?  Images and video frames are very rarely square.  You should size your network so the aspect ratio matches your images or video frames:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#square_network
This becomes even more important if the objects you are trying to find have a certain "shape".  Such as differentiating between ovals and circles, or squares and rectangles.
